# how to implement cascade dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I would like to implement a sample in MVC 4 by using bellow technics

1. N tier application
2. singleton pattern
3. WCF
4. SQL Server
5. Entity FrameWork
6. JSON
7. C#
8. MVC 4

My requirment is I need two drownlists one is for Country, second one is for States

When i select Country dropdown , need to load only those country related states.

How can i do it by using all the above techniques.

Comment: There is a search engine called Google, try it: http://www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by learning MVC tutorials that are available on many websites like asp.net etc.